# Ember CLI Download Excel [Save As] - blob/binary format Error

Tags: ember.js

I'm making an AJAX POST request from ember-cli to django rest framework in order to enable user to download excel/xls file. However, I'm stuck into formating problem, the file pops up but the content of the xls is not in correct format.

Here's the code I use in the controller:

```
  Ember.$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://api.dev.maspa.biz/api/v1/panel/catalog/export",
    data: 'ids=' + ids,
    success: function(data) {
      var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
      hiddenElement.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' + encodeURI(data);
      hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
      hiddenElement.download = 'export.xls';
      hiddenElement.click();
    },
  })
```

Looking for your helpful reply.

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of data which is returned from server? If it is binary you may faced with some problems. `hiddenElement.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)` may resolve your issue. (convert `data` to binary array named `blob`.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using an ember addon to handle this export for you? It could be more reliable than coding it yourself.

Check out this add-on - https://github.com/roofstock/ember-cli-data-export.